# Adapting NP-F 7.4-7.2v to 6-6.3v for old camcorder power (JVC GR-AX280)

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, camera, conversion

So my first time posting I have a JVC GR-AX280 that has a 6v to 6.3v DC input range at 1.8A.

The goal is to adapt future proof NPF style 7.4-7.2v batteries via a mount adapter as its format of batteries are dead but I don't know or what to use to step down the voltage exactly and it has to be compact.

Now bricked the first one *(family one without a tape in it)* using direct 7.4v it worked for about 10min without issue at first testing however upon testing again later it stopped working althoughether tho looking at schematics there is no protection in between power and IC chips in similar models so got a new one coming to replace the internals.

Comment: I am curious. Why 'future proof' equipment that's been obsolete for close to 20 years? Because unless you like the retro-ness of it (or want to learn), you'll save time, money and frustration by just ditching it.

Comment: Preservation of family archives and the gear used to create them, if I was to shoot something today depending on needs it would be on my Sony A7RIII and or HVR-Z5E with external recorders of course.